# App Engine Cursor limitation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, indexing, cursor

I am using the App Engine [Cursor Class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/cursorclass) to iterate through large result sets. Everything works fine retrieving the limit if 1000 records at a time until I reach a magical number of 250156 total documents (I know there are more in the index matching the query conditions). Each of the first 250 requests returns a cursor that can be used successfully to retrieve the next set of 1000 results. The last request in the chain returns 156 documents in the results and no next cursor.

To see if there was some limit on the number of successive search request on a chain I set the result limit to 500 documents instead of 100. 500 requests went through before the same behavior kicked in as the 501st request return 156 records and no next cursor.

Is there some undocumented limitation I am running up against? Basically, I am doing looping in taskqueue with limit =1000 (or 500):

```
options = search.QueryOptions(limit=limit, number_found_accuracy=10000,
    cursor=next_cursor, ids_only=True)

query = search.Query(query_string=q, options=options)
namespace = namespace_manager.get_namespace()

results = search.Index(name=index_name,
    namespace=namespace).search(query)

recs = len(results.results)
next_cursor=results.cursor
```

Any ideas or documentation of limitations would be great.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're not simply hitting the end of the results? As in, whatever larger number you think you have is actually just an estimate, like in Google's search results? (I'm sure you've encountered that before: you do a search and it says some weirdly specific, large number of results found, but if you sit there paging through the results, you eventually come to the end, having only seen a small fraction of the number initially promised.) Can you add or remove a document and see if the number changes?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure. I have the same data set in BigQuery, where I can get counts. Also, I have tried completely independent queries with distinct expected results above 250156 records, both return exactly that many results. I am sure this has nothing to do with the SearchResults.number_found(), which is only an estimate if the result is larger than the number_found_accuracy query parameter.

Comment: @Martha, I liked your idea about removing a record in the current results to see what the behavior is. I did so and the result indeed contains one less record. Investigating further with other queries... Note: I realize that I reported the count incorrectly above. Everywhere that I said 250156 should have been 250126.

Comment: After many more queries I found that cursors function as expected, even with 460k+ total documents. I don't know what is happening with the queries that motivated this submission, but it is clear that it is not an App Engine cursor limitation as originally suspected. I consider the original issue to be closed. For those interested in a great study on App Engine query performance based on the parameters 'limit' and 'number_found_accuracy', see [Stucky 2014] (https://github.com/VertNet/webapp/blob/master/docs/api_cnt_performance_analysis.pdf). Thanks @Martha for the simple and effective idea.